# SQL install in Debian Jessie 8.0 failling: "Unable to locate package mysql" but sourcers.list is already configured.

Tags: debian, apt, mysql

I'm using Debian 8.0 Jessie and trying to install mysql.

My /etc/apt/sources.list is ok but I don't have enough reputation points to post the configurations once only two links are allowed, but with some spaces, my configuration is as follow:

```
deb http: // ftp.debian.org/debian jessie main non-free contrib
deb-src http: // ftp.debian.org/debian jessie main non-free contrib
deb http: // ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http: // ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb http: // http.debian.net/debian/ jessie main non-free contrib
deb http: // security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb http: // http.debian.net/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http: // http.debian.net/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb http: // http.debian.net/debian/ jessie-backports main contrib non-free
#Wine-hq
deb https: // dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian/ jessie main
deb http: // download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/ wheezy contrib
### deb-multimedia.
### Chave GPG: apt-get update && apt-get install deb-multimedia-keyring
deb http: // www. deb-multimedia.org jessie main non-free
deb http: // www. deb-multimedia.org jessie-backports main
```

And I'm typing:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql
```

And receiving

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mysql
```

Also:

If I type 
`mysql`

I receive
`bash: mysql: command not found`

And, finally, there's no `mysql` file under `/etc/init.d`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Debian package named `mysql`.  The packages (that one probably will be installing manually) are named `mysql-client`, `mysql-server`, and `mysql-testsuite`, with version-specific packages available if one does not want "the current version".

## Further reading

- [mysql](https://wiki.debian.org/MySql).  Debian wiki.  Debian.

Answer (score 0):

You can install and start `mysql` through :

```
 apt-get install mysql-server 
 service mysql start
```

Or using the [MySQL APT Repository](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#apt-repo-fresh-install)

```
wget https://repo.mysql.com//mysql-apt-config_0.8.1-1_all.deb
dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.1-1_all.deb
apt-get update
apt-get install mysql-server 
service mysql start
```